# ElasticSearch : series of events (is it possible to create an ordered list ?)

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, logstash, sequences

I'm using recent version of Logstash, ElasticSearch and Kibana to parse/filter/stock/query and visualize logs. 
I'm working on a series of events.

---

This logs record users making events at differents time (in a certain order).

Example :

```
 {
   "name" : "user1",
   "event" : "event1",
   "timestamp" : 31/Dec/2014:23:50:00 +0000
 }
 {
   "name" : "user1",
   "event" : "event2",
   "timestamp" : 31/Dec/2014:23:52:00 +0000
 }
 {
   "name" : "user2",
   "event" : "event1",
   "timestamp" : 31/Dec/2014:23:52:00 +0000
 }
 {
   "name" : "user2",
   "event" : "event1",
   "timestamp" : 31/Dec/2014:23:57:00 +0000
 }
 {
   "name" : "user3",
   "event" : "event3",
   "timestamp" : 31/Dec/2014:23:50:00 +0000
 }
```

I would like to **count the number of unique user for each possible event sequence**. Answered this question : **how many users did a certain sequence of events ?**

For this example, as a result of query, I would like something like that :

```
 "EVENTS" : [
     {
         "key" : "event1", "doc_count" : 2,
         "CHILDREN " : [
             {"key" : "event2", "doc_count" : 1}
             {"key" : "event1", "doc_count" : 1}
         ]
     },
     {
         "key" : "event3","doc_count" : 1     
     }
 ]
```

Here we can say : 
There are 2 users that start by "event1", 1 continue with "event2" and other with "event1"
and there is 1 user starting by "event3".

---

So, I would like to **aggregate on users' events in an order way** (starting by first, then by following events).

I'm new to this, but I already did a lot of research and a big brainstorming.

- I already did aggregation on field "name", then aggregation on field "event" sorted by timestamp, that give me ordered events by user. But then, **I can't make an aggregation over/from this buckets result**, taking first, then second... . Or do I miss something ?
- Then I was wondering a new way of indexing my data : create unique id for each user and update/upsert event in an ordered list time after time. So, be able to **manipulate an array field by appending items and preserving the order**. I have already tried on tag, but this is a non ordered array, so I can't access to tags[0], tags[1]... . Same for nested object. Do I right ?
- Last idea I have it is if I could have a ordered list by appening **iterative field name** as order of appearance. Something like : `{"0":"event1", "1":"event2", "2":"event3"}`

But I can't really figure out a simple way to do this.

Any idea(s)/ help ?

Thanks !

Comment: Just an idea, is strict ordering really necessary? Elastic search already provides with timeline of events for visualization with kibana. For instance, if `event1` and `event2` happens, in many situations it is likely to have a similar effect to having `event1` and then `event2`. I can't imagine a really critical scenario where that ordering between events is significant, and I would like to know kindly.